# Set debugging target for Office 365 task pane app to Windows Store App version of Word/Excel?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, office365-apps

I am developing a Task pane app that uses the Javascript API for Office.  Currently, when I hit F5 to run Word or Excel to debug it, the Desktop version of Word/Excel launches with my Task pane app inside it.  How can I configure Visual Studio 2013 to launch my Task pane app using the WinRT (Windows Store App/Metro) version of Word/Excel instead?

Comment: Hi Robert, do you mean the version of Word or Excel found on WinRT devices such as the Surface? There is currently no modern version of Office available in the Windows Store.

Comment: @DorreneBrown Yes but on the Surface 2 running WinRT, not the older Surface.  Are you saying that the Javascript API for Office Apps is only supported on non-WinRT systems like the Desktop PCs or Surface Pros?

Comment: @DorreneBrown I just jumped into my Surface 2 and ran Word. Under the Insert menu choice there was an option to Insert apps.  I followed the See All link to the Office store and got the Microsoft Translator app.  I then went back to Word, chose Insert Apps again, and selected Translator from the list of available apps.  Microsoft Translator showed up in the Task Pane ready to go.  Doesn't this indicate that Task pane apps using the Javascript API for Office do work with the Surface 2?